# Jquery postback not working on mvc 4 client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I'm trying to simply create a json postback so I can update some controls on the client side.  I cant find a good example to show this.

Here's what I got so far which appears to be firing off an alert from the controller but keeps saying 'undefined' object on client side.

What is best practice method of achieving this as I dont know how to debug javascript in the same manner as regular code?  :( I'm using vs2012 express, mvc 4, jquery 1.7.1 and jquery mobile 1.1.

My controller  Time/Index:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index()
{
     var msg = "hello there";  //test message
     return Json(msg);
}
```

My client side:

```
function populateUserDetails() {
     var user = {};
     user.UserId = $("#UserId").val();    // potential fields i may use once i get it working
     $.post('Time/Index', user, updateFields, 'json');
 };

updateFields = function (data) {
    alert("hi " + data.msg);
    $("#textEntered").val(data.msg);
};
```

*** *UPDATE* *************

fixed it by wrapping returned object in controller into a temporary class:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        var response = new {msg = "hello there"};   //here's what i changed
        return Json(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line of code as below.

return Json(response,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

so it should be  like that

[HttpPost]

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var response = new {msg = "hello there"};  
   //here's what i changed

   return Json(response,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```